# how to consume two source stream with table API in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

I have a Flink Job that use the python table api. Now my application is going to consume an additional source stream. I am curious what the recommended way to consume multiple source stream with table API.

Additional information:

The two input streams are just two source of events. I want to aggregate them together with window operation. It is like [union operation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#union) in DataStream

Thanks!

Comment: What is the relationship between the two streams? For example, do you intend to join them in some way? Or should they be processed independently?

Comment: @DavidAnderson updated the question. These two streams are just two source, I would like to aggregate them with window operations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Table/SQL equivalent to DataStream union is the [Table union operation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/tableapi/#union) or the [SQL union operation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/set-ops/#union).